# C++ Reading text file line by line

Tags: c++, methods, while-loop, line, ifstream

I want to read a txt file and I want to process each number on the line one by one, apply some functions and pass to the other line. When the line is over, I don't know how to apply the same operations to the lines below. Methods will get a different output from each line that is why I have to handle each line separately.

```
int number;
ifstream readingFile("a.txt");

while(readingFile >> number){
    /* Methods will be applied to each number in the line */
}

readingFile.close();
```

a.txt

`23 4 555`

`2123 44 21 4`

`1 45 667 2 112`

Comment: Read the whole line with std::getline() into a std::string then use a istringstream to get the numbers out of the string.

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365202/c-reading-lines-of-integers-from-cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365202/c-reading-lines-of-integers-from-cin)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read file line by line using ifstream in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Working C++ Code**

To clear doubts Test it in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php
Just copy-paste execute

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream> 
int main () 
{   
    //code create a file with numbers
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("file.txt");
    myfile << "123 12  32323\n 4444 55 535\n";
    myfile.close();
    
    std::ifstream input( "file.txt" );
    for( std::string eachLine; getline( input, eachLine ); )
    {
        std::istringstream strm(eachLine);
        std::string splitedLines;
        // loop for each string and add to the vector
        while ( strm >> splitedLines )
            {
            std::stringstream geek(splitedLines);
            int num;    // can be int, float or double
            geek >>num;
            //perform action on all num in each line one by one 
            std::cout<<num<<std::endl;
            }    
        }
    return 0; 
}
```

**Edit:** **PythonCode** read numbers one by one in each line

```
fileName = open('a.txt', 'r')
line = fileName.readline() //reading first line
while(line):
    for eachStringNumber in line.split():
        number = int(eachStringNumber)
        /// Methods will be applied to each number in the line ///
    line = fileName.readline() // reading lines one by one in each loop
fileName.close()
```

Comment: The question is about c++, please don't give answers for a wrong language or standard, which is older than 20 years. Please rewrite your answer for c++11

Comment: Sorry added Python Code in the beginning

Comment: Well both <string.h> and <string> works, still <string> is more c++ revelent hence updated.

Comment: Save the numbers in a vector, line by line or the entire file in one go.